# activerecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Depot < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :designation
  has_many :articles
end

class Famille < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :designation
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :depot
  belongs_to :famille
  attr_accessible :code, :designation
end
```

This error appears when I try to create a new article with depot and famille fields, how can I resolve it?

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ArticlesController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: depot, famille
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your Article class:

```
attr_accessible :code, :designation, :depot_id, :famille_id
```

Comment: i think it should be attr_accessible :code, :designation, :depot_id, :famille_id and still the same problem !

Comment: sorry for the typo. Are you sure that it's not working? Can you post your controllers action?

Comment: can you show your form code from the view, how are you passing the depot and familie?

Comment: can you change `f.text_field :depot` to `f.text_field :depot_id` and the same with `familie`

Comment: yes a new record is saved but with these information !! 1 1 #<Depot:0x007f8095613b28> #<Famille:0x007f8093581e28>

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, what do you mean with `these` information?